# Mysql php: How to join same table multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

- `Team` table has:

  ```
     ID   |   TEAM  
  --------+----------
     1    |     A
     2    |     B
  ```
- `Result` table has:

  ```
    fk_ID1  |   fk_ID2  |  RESULT
  ----------+-----------+-----------
      1     |     2     |   5:0
      2     |     1     |   2:3
  ```

How to `Inner JOIN` table, to get: `(A 5:0 B) & (A 2:3 B)`?

My code example:

```
public function getResultList($limit, $offset) {
    $query = "  SELECT result_id,
                       t1.name name1,
                       t2.name name2,
                       team1_goals,
                       team2_goals,
                       date
                FROM results
                    INNER JOIN team t1 ON fk_tm1_id=tm_id
                    INNER JOIN team t2 ON fk_tm2_id=tm_id";
            $data = mysql::select($query);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Put and format your code in the post, don't attach it as a image.

Comment: @Devon, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to answer this as purely an SQL question, which it is.  You need to assign a table alias when joining the same table two or more times.

You seem to only be assigning aliases to the column.  To assign an alias to a column or table, you can add the alias directly after the column or table name (AS can also be used but isn't necessary for MySQL)

A common thing is to number the tables as t1, t2, t3, etc.

```
SELECT t1.name name1, t2.name name2 FROM ...
INNER JOIN team_table t1 ON ...
INNER JOIN team_table t2 ON ...
```

This aliases the first join as t1 and the second join as t2, which you would use when accessing data from that specific join (SELECT t1.name).

Comment: and add `WHERE` clause to exclude results for same ids

Comment: @Devon, updated, tried, not working... Maybe something I've missed?

Comment: I agree, this answer is pretty good but needs further explanation where the ellipsis exist, (...). I realize this is where you would insert this information in your own situation but the main challenge is the syntax of the solution which is partially left out.